# python unicode string matching

Tags: python, regex, string, unicode, matching

I have a list of words converted into  a list of `unciode` strings but i am not able to match the end strings of a particular word from a list of strings as for example:

list which contains of strings of which it needs to be removed.For example 
`उपलब्धियां` is the word when converted to unicode is `u'\u0909\u092a\u0932\u092c\u094d\u0927\u093f\u092f\u093e\u0902'`

list which contains of strings which if found at the end of a word in unicode needs to be removed 
`r3_bad= [u"0900", u"0901", u"0902",u"0903"];`
in this case is `u0902` is at the end from the bad string list so to be removed.

i tried

```
if re.search(r'u$[0-3]',word[-1]) :
```

it does not returns true
i don't know why.

please help thanks in advance.

Comment: Just print `r'u$[0-3]'` and `word[-1]` and you should understand why Python cannot find the *former* in the *latter*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why RegEx? I think you need something like plain string comparison:

```
s = u'\u0909\u092a\u0932\u092c\u094d\u0927\u093f\u092f\u093e\u0902'
r3_bad= [u'\u0900',u'\u0901',u'\u0902',u'\u0903']

print s # output: उपलब्धियां
if s[-1] in r3_bad: print s[:-1] # output: उपलब्धिया
```

Comment: in my case i am getting an error as such as: "Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode"                                                   the type of r3_bad is list and type of the s as in your answer is unicode. please help

Comment: Operator 'in' searches any iterable object so you can use another unicode string instead of list, it's all the same:

r3_bad = u'\u0900\u0901\u0902\u0903'